# Convert String with paths denoted with dot into a filename

Tags: java, string, file

I have a properties file

```
{Content}
com.some.that.file.txt = com.some.dest
com.fold.cust.dir = com.some.dest
```

Where the key denotes the name of a directory to copy to {Value}=com.some.dest

I have replaced dots with "/" but with this i cannot retain the filename e.g file.txt becomes file/txt.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: You need to replace all but the last dot.

Comment: Except if the filename contains more than one dot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`String.replaceAll(regex, replacement)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with the right regex:

```
String filename = value.replaceAll("\\.(?=.*\\.)", "/");
```

This regex matches dots, but only if there's another dot somewhere after the matched dot, checked using a "look ahead", which has syntax `(?=regex)`.

Here's a test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "com.some.that.file.txt";
    String filename = value.replaceAll("\\.(?=.*\\.)", "/");
    System.out.println(filename);
}
```

Output:

```
com/some/that/file.txt
```

#### Edited:

To find the directory names, use this:

```
String dirname = filename.replaceAll("/(?!.*/).*", "");
```

or in one line:

```
String dirname = value.replaceAll("\\.(?=.*\\.)", "/").replaceAll("/(?!.*/).*", "");
```

This extra step uses a "negative look ahead", which has syntax `(?!regex)`, to match a slash only if there *isn't* a slash somewhere after the matched slash and then the regex matches everything after that using `.*`

Comment: Yes, it worked but does not identify directories. Any pattern for that?

Comment: @M.Hussaini Yes - there is a pattern: See "edited" section at bottom of my answer